# Assign a session value to a Model Property in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, razor

I'm trying to assign a session value to a Model Property in Razor view like following

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Image, new { @Value = Session["PICTURE"].ToString() })
```

But this is not working properly , getting following error when session is null

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Try `Session["PICTURE"] as string` instead. I think your session may be `null`, when `null` use `.ToString()` you will get that's exception.

Comment: Never set the `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method. You assign the value to the `Image` property of the model before you pass it to the view.

Comment: @TooNDinDarkDevil but how to extract that session value as string then ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke so How can I do this ? whats you suggesting ?

Comment: In your `GET` method, you assign the value, but you also need to check if its not `null` first.

Comment: @kez `string stringValue = Session["PICTURE"] as string` you can code like this. :)

Comment: @kez If you don't sure the session is declare, you can check it before getting session value by `string stringValue = (Session == null ? (string)null : Session["PICTURE"] as string);`. Let try ! :)

Comment: The error message seems come from NRE (NullReferenceException), it may fit as duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it.